# Batch file to search for a file, then delete

Tags: batch-file

I want to find a file `fileName.txt` on my disk and then delete it.

I can't just `del C:\some\file\path\fileName.txt` because I don't know `C:\some\file\path`.

How do I first search and then delete from there?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @user1061378 For examples of looping through all drives, have a look at this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21410817/3395469).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Notepad
2. Type

`CD C:\`

`DEL filename.extension /s`

`Exit`

3. Save the file as `delete.bat`

Comment: I am asking for batch file not for cmd

Comment: @user1061378 edited for batch file.

Comment: It is working correctly only if we knows the drive where this file is located. We need to delete file without knowing dirve

Comment: How many drives do you have? You could just iterate through the drives in the batch file, as a simple solution.

Comment: It will be end user drives, so we can't estimate, can you please tell me how we can iterate/loop for drive?

Comment: Have you done ANY research at all? You seem to be expecting us to come up with an all-encompassing fix without explaining what you've tried to far and where you're stuck.

Comment: No I didn't. Actaully, I am not aware of any batch command script. All I need is to done this task ONLY.

Comment: I've started you off, you can finish it now.

Comment: @spikey_richie i'm with you; this isn't a script writing service and some people are super ungrateful and lazy.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to search your entire system for that file and delete all instances of it:

```
@echo off

for /r "c:" %%A in (fileName.txt) do (
    del /f /q "%%A"
)
```

Just be careful with what you're deleting; if you need to run it across drives other than `c:` we can tweak it a bit.

Reference: [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), [del](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)

Comment: why c drive? it can be anywhere

Comment: anywhere as in across multiple drives, or over a network where the locations aren't necessarily mapped as drives? this is the tweaking I was referring to in my answer since it wasn't specified in your question.

Comment: but it is not working for me except if file in desktop

Comment: is your user profile on your c: drive? did you change the file name?